# Filtering Nodes in Kendo Angular TreeView with Flat Data Binding

Tags: telerik, kendo-treeview, kendo-angular-ui

I have a kendo angular tree-view with flat data binding. There is a section for filtering the nodes with heterogenous data(search elements inside the treeview). Any update how to filter the nodes for flat data ?